# InterlockedExchange issue with C28112/3

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis, volatile, visual-studio-2017

I am getting a couple of code analysis issues:

> (774): warning C28113: Accessing a local variable lAbort via an
>   Interlocked function:  This is an unusual usage which could be
>   reconsidered.
>
> (775): warning C28112: A variable (lAbort) which is accessed via an
>   Interlocked function must always be accessed via an Interlocked
>   function. See line 774:  It is not always safe to access a variable
>   which is accessed via the Interlocked* family of functions in any
>   other way.

from this code:

```
BOOL CHttpDownloader::Abort()
{
  volatile LONG lAbort = 0;
  InterlockedExchange(&lAbort, m_lAbort);
  return (lAbort != 0);
}
```

I confess that this code / class is not even mine. The original author isn't supporting it right now, and I have not used these types of `volatile` variables myself.

However, it has always worked, and it is not clear on the right way to revise the code to address the warning.

Comment: Legacy code had little choice but to use `volatile`, since C++ did not define a suitable memory model. That is no longer the case; modern versions of C++ have addressed this issue, and modern versions of Microsoft's compiler have begun to offer support for it. For backwards compatibility, the original Microsoft-specific semantics for `volatile` remain the default when targeting x86 processors, but you are encouraged to update your code when possible. See also [the MSVC documentation for `volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx).

Comment: Anyway, that's just an aside. Regarding your question and the warnings, I'm not sure what you find to be unclear about them. They seem pretty obvious to me. What would be the point in using Interlocked semantics for a *local* variable? Presumably, that local variable can't possibly be accessed outside of the function, so it's saying this is unusual. Is this supposed to be re-entrant code? And the second warning is saying that the last line (`return (lAbort != 0)`) is probably wrong, since it doesn't use the interlocked semantics.

Comment: @CodyGray The short and honest answer is I do not know. But I have just found that there is an update to the HTTP Download library here: http://www.naughter.com/httpdownloaddlg.html. It says that it has addresses code analysis issues. So I am trying it.

Comment: @CodyGray New classes didn't work. I have attempted to contact the original author again.

Comment: @CodyGray Actually, this issue is resolved. I had to do a full re-compile using the revised classes from the link in my comment.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it should protect access to m_lAbort (might be changed concurrently) but as written it protects access to lAbort (which cannot be written concurrently). So the compiler emitted good warnings pointing to a problem in the code.

Comment: @WernerHenze Thanks. This issue was resolved. I had not realised the author had updated the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes had been revised by the author. That method now looks like this:

```
BOOL CHTTPDownloader::Abort()
{
  return (m_lAbort != 0);
}
```

Here are the revised classes:

http://www.naughter.com/httpdownloaddlg.html